# Find words between two phrases

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract the words between two phrases. For example assuming I have the following paragraph:

> One day after they had made porridge for their breakfast they walked
>   out into the wood while the porridge was cooling And while they were
>   walking a little girl came into the house This little girl had golden
>   curls that tumbled down her back to her waist and everyone called her
>   by Goldilocks.

I would like to get all the words between *little girl* and *golden curls* as well as 2 words before and after these words.

Is there an easy way to do so? I was getting the index of the start of phrases but it lead to quite lengthy code

Comment: but wouldn't that give me words not phrase?

Comment: One liner: `txt.replace('porridge for', '~').replace('golden curls', '~').split('~')`

Comment: @Joe124, can you provide the desired output?

Comment: regex may help, you way want to experiment a little bit https://regex101.com/r/MHAPhX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [regular expressions](https://regex101.com/r/qIZHwP/1):

```
import re
match = re.search(r'(\w+ \w+) porridge for (.+) golden curls (\w+ \w+)', text)
whole_match = match.group(0)
two_words_before = match.group(1)
phrase_in_middle = match.group(2)
two_words_after = match.group(3)
```

### Edit

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/qIZHwP/5) for finding multiple instances of `little girl ... golden curls`:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(?=( (\w+ \w+) little girl (.+) golden curls (\w+ \w+)) )', text)  # use ?= for look-ahead in order to find overlapping matches
first_match = matches[0][1:]  # tuple has form (full_match, two_words_before, phrase_in_middle, two_words_after)
last_match = matches[-1][1:]  # as above
```

Comment: @pygo *set* the example output? If you want to see the output, follow the link

Comment: Excellent answer...May I ask what happens if I want little girl? This phrase is shown twice in the sentence. What if I want the one near golden curls...so the words in between would be 'had' only

Comment: hope this works for you without using re

**' '.join(a.split()[4:6]) + ' ' + a[a.index('porridge'):a.index('curls')] + ' '.join(a[a.index('that'):].split()[:2])**